# Comparable arrays in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Coming from a Swift world I'm trying to figure out how to use comparable functions like `min()` or `max()` on an array of objects. In Swift I would use the comparable protocol  -

```
class Car: Comparable {
    let year: Int

    static func < (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.year < rhs.year
    }

    static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.year == rhs.year
    }
}
```

But how would you do the same in Kotlin? I've tried this but I'm not sure if it's the right approach, or how I would implement the iterable function -

```
data class Car(val year: Int): Comparable<Car>, Iterable<Car> {

    override fun compareTo(other: Car) = when {
        this.year < other.year -> -1
        this.year > other.year -> 1
        else -> 0
    }

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<Car> {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: So your end goal is to be able to call `min` and `max` on an array of Cars? You can already do that with your `Comparable` implementation, although it could be simpler (`this.year - other.year`).

Comment: The `compareTo` method looks fine, but you don't need the car to be an `Iterable`. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your implementation there's no issue, but you could make it simpler:

```
data class Car(val year: Int): Comparable<Car> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Car) = year - other.year
}
```

You should not implement the `Iterable` interface, because this would make the `Car` a kind of a collection.

Running the following example with the given `Car` implementation

```
listOf(Car(2004), Car(2007), Car(2001)).run {
    println(this)
    println(min())
    println(max())
    println(sorted())
}
```

yields the output of

```
[Car(year=2004), Car(year=2007), Car(year=2001)]
Car(year=2001)
Car(year=2007)
[Car(year=2001), Car(year=2004), Car(year=2007)]
```

Comment: Right ok. I think it's the `run` bit I was missing. I was trying to call `max()` on the list directly  `listOf(Car(2004), Car(2007), Car(2001)).max()` which I could only do if I implemented the `Iterable` interface.

Comment: There is actually no difference and your code there runs fine as well. I'd assume you missed a closing brace somewhere and thus the compiler tried to call `max()` on a `Car`.